# Access list custom setting field from Visualforce?

Tags: visualforce

I want to access custom setting field from `Visualforce`. Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: Hi Dinu, welcome to SFSE, please take some time to read [ask] and take the [tour] in order to get familiar with the kind of questions you should ask here. this will increase the likely-hood of getting answers. Show at least some level of effort (in research) when posting questions, and we will be more than happy to help. thanks!

Answer (score 7):

It is only "hierarchy" custom settings that can be accessed directly in Visualforce via the [$Setup](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_setup.htm) global merge field. This type of custom setting only has a single record for any given user, so the record to use is tied down.

"List" custom settings can have many records and so logic in an Apex controller is needed to select the correct row/rows for a page and pass it/them to the Visualforce logic. See the "List Custom Settings" section of the [Custom Settings Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm) documentation for the available Apex methods.